# Load Schema in Dgraph

Tags: database, dgraph

I can't create type in Dgraph. read https://tour.dgraph.io/master/intro/3/# but not work. pleas help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type system is available in Dgraph v1.1.0 or later. Double-check that you're using v1.1.0 to follow the instructions in the Tour.